# On inequalities for $\dfrac{1}{\zeta(s)}$, $\dfrac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ and $\log (\zeta(s))$

Tags: proof-explanation, riemann-zeta, estimation

The following is Section 3.6. of Titchmarsh's book The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function:

[image]

My questions are:

1- Eq. 3.6.1 holds for $\sigma >1$. Eq. 3.6.2 holds for $\sigma > 1 - A/\log t$. There are two things about the green-underlined equation: (a) The second term must be $-A_2|\sigma -1| \log^2 t$ and the absolute value operator comes from triangle inequity. (b) This equation is a result comes from combining Eqs. 3.6.1 and 3.6.2, so it holds for $\sigma > 1$, the intersection of two domains. Holding this for $\sigma >1$ and not for $\sigma > 1 - A/\log t$ ruins the original purpose of Titschman which was to show that there is some narrow rectangular with vertices $1 \pm \epsilon(t) + it_0 $ and $1 \pm \epsilon(t) + it $ where $\zeta(s)$ is non-zero. Am I right by these two remarks?

2- I suppose the correct inequality for the red-underlined one is $1 - A/\log t < \sigma <1$ (a typo). (a) To get Eq. 3.6.3 we supposed $\sigma -1 = \log^{-9} t$ (so $\sigma > 1$) and Eq. 3.6.4 is a result from Eq. 3.6.3 but the common domain for the two is empty! (b) The correct form of Eq. 3.6.4 is $$|\zeta(\sigma+it)| = |\zeta(\sigma+it) - \zeta(1+it) + \zeta(1+it)| > |\zeta(1+it)| - |\zeta(\sigma+it) - \zeta(1+it)| > A \log^{-7} t - B (1- \sigma) \log^{2} t,$$ where $B$ is the positive constant from the $O$ of Eq. 3.6.2. But $A=B$ is considered! Am I right by these two remarks?

3- $\dfrac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \dfrac{d}{ds} \log \zeta(s)$, i.e. the differentiation is done on $s$ and not on the real part of $s$. So Eq. 3.6.7 is incorrect. Can this proof for estimating $\log \zeta(s)$ be adjusted and if so how? Otherwise, how to prove $\log \zeta(s) = O( \log^9 t)$?

Comment: for an analytic function the derivative is also the partial derivative wr to either variable up to a constant - $s=\sigma+it, f'(s)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \sigma}(s)=\frac{1}{i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(s)$ - this is a trivial consequence of the C-R equations and defintions

Comment: @Conrad Thanks! Let me review the CA book that I have studied and I will reply soon

Comment: @Conrad, yes! That's right. Thank you very much :))

Comment: and for the rest of the questions, Titchmarsh is old style so his notations and arguments are sometimes confusing; for example 3.6.3 has nothing to do with any $\sigma$ it is just an inequality about $\zeta(1+it)$ and an absolute constant $A$; equation 3.6.2 is actually true for any $\sigma$ as it is just the usual fundamental theorem of calculus, so in particular we can apply it with $\sigma < 1$ (which has nothing to do with the $\sigma$ used to prove 3.6.3); simlarly the various $A,B$ may be different at different inequalities even though they are still denoted $A,B$ and so on

Comment: @Conrad, let me re-read the text again with your notes I will reply today. Thanks a lot.

Comment: my advice is to complement Titchmarsh which is an advanced treatise with more modern introductory books like Freitag Complex Analysis (vol 1) or Apostol Introduction to Analytic Number Theory which are both very gentle introductions to the subject and have much more detailed explanations of the stuff in the first three chapters of Titchmarsh as the stuff there is classic and well understood; from chapter 4 on though stuff gets into areas that even today are on the boundaries of research

Comment: @Conrad, I have studied Apostol Introduction to Analytic Number Theory in detail with all exercises and for CA I have studied Churchill's Complex Variables and Applications again in deepest. But it was several years ago and I will start my PhD in 20 days and no time to review ANT very unfortunately.

Comment: My suggestion is to keep those handy and take a quick look when you get stumped and generally have stuff at hand to consult as needed; the other thing to keep in mind is that Titchmarsh uses old style notation in many places so it's good to translate those in modern notation like $O$ and $<<$ say first because I think they get clearer that way

Comment: @Conrad, I re-studied all Ch-13 of Apostol's book and resolved my confusions. In Apostol $\sigma \ge 1$ for Equations 3.6.5 and 3.6.6 of Titchmarsh! And with lots of attempt still $\sigma > 1- A \log^9 t$ stated for Eqs. 3.6.5 and 3.6.6 and 3.67 is wrong...

Comment: It is $\sigma >1-A\log ^{-9} t$ and the results mentioned follow immediately - eg the bound on $1/\zeta$ follows from 3.6.4 directly etc

Comment: @Conrad, Eq 3.6.1 is used in the three mentioned equations and that's the problem! bc Eq 3.6.1 is not valid for $\sigma \le 1$, probably that's why Apostol limits the domain to $\sigma \ge 1$ in his Thm 13.7

Comment: @Conrad maybe the three Eqs 3.6.5, 3.6.6 and 3.67 are valid for $\sigma >1-A\log ^{-9} t$ but it needs another valid proof, i.e. without use of Eq 3.6.1 (?)

Comment: Do not see where u use 3.6.1 for those; 3.6.1 is just used to get bounds for $\zeta(1+it)$ which are then used in 3.6.2 to move to the left of the line $1$

Comment: @Conrad, 3.6.1 is used to get green-underlined inequality which is valid for the same domain as 3.6.1 i.e. $\sigma > 1$. Then for 3.6.3 $\sigma -1 = A_3 log^{-9} t$ is used which means $\sigma > 1$ since $\sigma = 1+ A_3 log^{-9} t$ and not $\sigma = 1- A_3 log^{-9} t$

Comment: You do not understand the structure of the proof - 3.6.1 is used to get a bound for $\zeta (1+it)$ using 3.6.2 for $\sigma >1$ however 3.6.2 and the green underlined equality have nothing to do with 3.6.1 and can be applied for $\sigma$ to the left of the line since it is just the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: @Conrad, how do you derive the green-underlined inequality? You use 3.6.1 (which is NOT valid for $\sigma \le 1$) AND you use 3.6.2 (which is valid for ALL $\sigma$). Then green-underlined inequality is valid for the intersection of the domains of validity of both 3.6.1 and 3.6.2.

Comment: @Conrad, $|\zeta(1+it)| > |\zeta(\sigma+it)| - |\zeta(1+it) - \zeta(\sigma+it)| > A_1 \frac{(\sigma -1)^{\frac34}}{\log^{\frac14} t} - A_2 (\sigma -1) \log^2 t$ and uses both 3.6.1 and 3.6.2 - and using 3.6.1 forces it to be valid for $\sigma > 1$

Comment: 3.6.3 is true regardless of anything because it is just a bound on $|\zeta(1+it)$; the first equality in 3.6.2 $\zeta(1+it)-\zeta(\sigma+it)$ is minus he integral from $1$ to $\sigma$ of the derivative is also true regardless as is the fundamental theorem of calculus; then using the logarithmic (square) bound on $\zeta'$ established earlier in theorem 3.5 and again valid near line $1$ both left and right gives the equation 3.6.4 for sigma to the left of $1$ and near enough which is what we need

Comment: **NOTE : This question no longer needs to be answered**