# The Three Lemmas of Section 3.9. of Titchmarsh's book

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

The following is Section 3.9. of Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function*:

[image]

In Lemma $\beta$, since $\rho_0$ is a zero between $s_0 - \frac12 r$ and $s_0$, so $Re (s_0 - \rho_0) > 0$ so both cases are the same; i.e. again in the second case, still $-Re \dfrac{f'(s_0)}{f(s_0)} < \dfrac{AM}{r} - Re \dfrac{1}{s_0 - \rho_0} < \dfrac{AM}{r}$. Am I right?

Note: It might not seem an important issue but it really is. I ignored at first but the subsequent two sections, this causes a great deal.

Comment: It's not a typo because $s_0-\rho_0$ is a negative real by the assumptions on $\rho_0$

Comment: @Conrad, yes! I am confused sometimes :( - Thank you I edited the OP

Comment: @Conrad, Actually I restudied Section 3.10 now and the issue I had encountered is removed. Should I delete the post then? I mean, still both cases are >AM/r and the second is just a better approximation?

Comment: @Conrad, sorry I know it's weird to ask this in here but your answers and hints have been great and I doubt that I will ever get an answer for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4843231/on-inequalities-for-dfrac1-zetas-dfrac-zetas-zetas-and-l . If you have time I would appreciate your help especially the third question is critical :)

Comment: **NOTE : This question no longer needs to be answered**